# Using the TABLE_DATE_RANGE function in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery for the first time in quite awhile, so I'm a bit rusty.

I'm using a public dataset that can be [found here for Reddit data.](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.2016_07)

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is create a query that extracts all data from 2017.

Basically, I want to use the BQ syntax specific equivalent of this, which is written using Standard SQL:

`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017*`

I know that would involve using the TABLE_DATA_RANGE function, but I'm stumped on the specific wording of it.

If I was using just one of the tables, it would look like this:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_UTC_USEC(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)) AS created_date
FROM
[fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.2017_06]
LIMIT
10
```

But I'm obviously trying to span this over multiple months.

Comment: What is wrong with `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017*`? Use standard SQL (not TABLE_DATE_RANGE using legacy SQL).

Comment: Because I'd like use BQ syntax to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(created_utc) AS created_date 
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_*`
LIMIT 10
```

It does what your query for one table does  - but for all tables for 2017 (not sure what actually the logic you are looking for in your query - but I hope you left it outside the question just for simplicity sake)

Note: you can use `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in your query to identify which exactly table specific row comes from  - for example:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS month, 
  COUNT(1) AS records  
FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_*`
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

with output as below

```sql
month    records     
-----    ---------
01       9,218,513   
02       8,588,120   
03       9,616,340   
04       9,211,051   
05       9,498,553   
06       9,597,725   
07       9,989,122   
08      10,424,133   
09       9,787,604   
10      10,281,718
```

In case if for whatever reason you still bound to BigQuery Legacy SQL - you can use below

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  FORMAT_UTC_USEC(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(created_utc)) AS created_date
FROM TABLE_QUERY([fh-bigquery:reddit_posts], "LEFT(table_id, 5) = '2017_'")  
LIMIT 10
```

But it is highly recommended to [migrate to Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `..2017*` and not `..2017_*` to catch the edge cases e.g. `201708_`?

Comment: i purposely put `2017_` as I believe `201708_` and `201707_` are outliers with zero rows in them.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant

Thanks for this, but again, I'm looking for the BQ specific syntax. I already know Standard SQL.

Comment: read answer again please. it provides two options - both for BigQuery - one is for Standard SQL and another one is for Legacy SQL! Isn't this what you asking?

Comment: "I'm looking for the BQ specific syntax" Why would you want to learn legacy SQL syntax? It's called "legacy" because it's not the preferred SQL dialect.

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed that originally.